# The links in the drop down tab are not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am using ReactStrap and the nav links in the drop down menu are not working properly (directing to page) in firefox. Works perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari etc... here is the link http://alimansour.herokuapp.com/

Here is the code for the Navbar

... Thank you in advance.

```
    <DropdownMenu right>
              <DropdownItem>
                <NavLink>
                  <Link
                    onClick={this.toggle}
                    to={"/client"}
                    style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "gray" }}
                  >
                    Client Side
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>
              </DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>
                <NavLink>
                  <Link
                    onClick={this.toggle}
                    to={"/server"}
                    style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "gray" }}
                  >
                    Server Side
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>
              </DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem divider />
              <DropdownItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/alzz0" target="_blank">
                  GitHub
                </NavLink>
              </DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. It has many errors that might give you a clue.

Comment: I opened your website and opened the console. there are errors you must see them